# What is Inbound Bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth

The hosting plan I'm about to get offers unlimited inbound bandwidth. What is this? I know it's not usual bandwidth since they charge highly for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Its when you download something from the internet to your server or when someone uploads to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the usual bandwidth load on a server is from downloads --- people getting pages/files from your site.  In otherwords, data leaving your site (outgoing).  Uploads to your site (incoming data), where people send you things, is the other kind.  Add them together, and you'll get the total bandwidth, or what other companies charge as simply "bandwidth".

Answer (score 0):

The wording is a bit misleading because there is really no such thing as unlimited bandwidth. That would require a feed of infinite size, which just doesn't exist. More than likely, as EK has already said, it means unlimited inbound traffic to the server.

Unfortunately, for most purposes it's the outbound traffic that is of importance, so that is what you really need to know about.